# notepad ++ How to remove words containing some characters, or a link

Tags: hyperlink, notepad++, text-editor

What expression can I use in Notepad ++ to remove all the words containing http??Not all the line but only the word!
Because I have a list of sentences and some of them contain a link that I would like to remove. Can someone help me??
thank you!!!

Comment: What do you mean by `word` in `remove all the words containing http`? Could you give some examples and what do you want to obtain?

Answer (score 1):

1. Search -> Replace (Ctrl + H).
2. In the Find what field type `http`.
3. In the Replace with field leave it blank.
4. Click Replace All

To replace a word containing http, then you'll need to do the same steps but in Search Mode select *Regex*, and in Find What change `http` to `\bhttp\b`.

Comment: Thanks for the cleanup @timrau - that's easier to understand.